# Responsive design for iPhone and iPad for game area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use the code below for my game. Everything is ok on iPhones. But on iPad the game area looks very small, like iPhone's area on iPad. Yes, I know, it's because of *areaWidth* and *areaHeight*. I want to make it a responsive design. What should I do for that?

Please, let me know if need more information.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var level: Level!

    let areaWidth: CGFloat = 33
    let areaHeight: CGFloat = 33

    let gameLayer = SKNode()

    let thingsLayer = SKNode()
    let tilesLayer = SKNode()

    var swipeFromColumn: Int?
    var swipeFromRow: Int?

    var swipeHandler: ((Swap) -> ())?

    var selectionSprite = SKSpriteNode()

    let cropLayer = SKCropNode()
    let maskLayer = SKNode()
```

Comment: I would recommend getting this book: https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/2d-apple-games-by-tutorials it shows how to set this up and much more

Comment: @Scriptable you recommend to pay $54.99 for lessons from 2016 years? Thanks :D

Comment: Under `Deployment Info` check if you have selected `Universal`.

Comment: "Learn how to make iOS, tvOS, macOS and watchOS games using Swift 4 and SpriteKit." Swift 4 was not released in 2016. The books are constantly updated for the latest release and you receive all of the updates for free.

Comment: @Kamran "Use Auto Layout"? That one?

Comment: @Kamran  I got it. Yes, there is Universal. Problem is - only game area for my square (match 3 game) is small. Others elements on the display are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution might be to make your areaWidth and areaHeight a factor of the view size. I would put this code in your viewDidLoad() for this view controller.

```
areaWidth: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width * 0.66
areaHeight = areaWidth
```

I assumed you wanted to keep the area as a square. Otherwise you could do:

```
areaHeight: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.height * 0.66
```

This would make your width and height about two thirds the width and height of the current view controller. You'll need to adjust those numbers to suit your needs, though.

**EDIT:**
Since this is an SKScene and not a ViewController class, there is no view property to use. Instead use the size of the SKScene in the `override init(size: CGSize)` function. First, change the properties to `var`:

```
var areaWidth: CGFloat
var areaHeight: CGFloat
```

Then add the following to `override init(size: CGSize)` (Don't forget to put it above super.init):

```
areaWidth = size.width * 0.66
areaHeight = areaWidth
super.init(size: size)
```

Still assuming you want to keep the area a square.

Comment: thank you! but I don't have in viewDidLoad() in GameScene.swift. If I put `let areaWidth: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width * 0.66` instead `let areaWidth: CGFloat = 33` then I have an error **Value of type '(GameScene) -> () -> (GameScene)' has no member 'view'**

Comment: My mistake. Try using: `areaWidth = size.width * 0.66` in your `override init(size: CGSize)` function. Don't forget to change areaWidth to a `var` instead of `let`.